# Exchange 2007 to Exchange 2010 Migration - Message flow problems

Tags: domain-name-system, exchange-2010, exchange-2007, migration

I've tried to migrate an exchange server 2007 to the newer 2010 on another server. I have installed the 2010 roles one after another (CAS -> Hub Transport -> Mailbox).

After installing each of these roles I configured these with the same settings as shown in Exchange 2007.

Afterwards I moved my own mailbox to the newer version of the exchange server.

Now I am experiencing problems with the message flow, the following works:

- Sending a mail from Exchange 2010 via external SMART-Host to Exchange
  2007
- Sending a mail from Exchange 2010 via external SMART-Host to any
  email

but the following scenarios doesn't seem to work:

- receive any email from Exchange 2007
- receive any emails from outside the exchange organization

In the queue manager in Exchange 2007, then I see one queue called Hub version 14. This queue everytime fails with a DNS query failed error.

I hope somebody can help me with my problem. ;-)

Kind regards,
Alexander

Comment: It sounds like mail destined for your mailbox on the 2010 server is being queued up on the 2007 server because it can't resolve the name of the new Exchange server. Try an nslookup on the 2007 server to test resolution.